# Datetime passed to a variable is treated as a string - Python

Tags: python, datetime, airflow, python-datetime, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am working on Airflow DAGs. I have two DAGs say DAG A and DAG B. I want to do some stuff in DAG B based on execution_date of DAG A. For this I am making use of Airflow variables.

In DAG A:

```
def set_execution_date(**kwargs):
    Variable.set('var_name',kwargs['execution_date'])
    status = Variable.get(time_status)
```

This updates my airflow variable with execution_date of DAG A like below:

[image]

Now I am using this value from airflow variable in DAG B:

```
def check_task_status(**kwargs):
    date= Variable.get('stream_execution_date')
    ti = get_task_instance('STREAMING_TEST', 'start_group', date)
```

My DAG B throws the below error for the above definition:

[image]

The datetime value stored in airflow variable is treated as a string when used in DAG B. Instead I would like to use it as a datetime value.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: variables don't change type by coincidence - so could you clarify what you mean by "*is passed as a variable to another defintion*"?

Comment: and note that a string representing date/time in ISO format can easily be parsed to datetime object with [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat).

Comment: I am working on Airflow DAG. So I am passing the execution_date of say DAG A to airflow Variable and using this value in another DAG say DAG B. The date value is stored as a string in airflow Variable which is causing me this error

Comment: @MrFuppes Could you please help me how this can be treated as a datatime in DAG B with proper function?

Comment: @Rajalakshmi Can you please share the code in which you are getting errors, so that we can check and give proper answers?

Comment: I have tried using datetime.strptime(execution_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z") but the value i get is not as expected. On using this above function I get  2021-06-17 08:20:04.631151+00:00 instead I want it to be 2021-06-17T08:20:04.631151+00:00

Comment: I am performing the below action:
In DAG A:


def set_exec_date(**kwargs):


    Variable.set('var_name',kwargs['execution_date'])


In DAG B:


    Variable.get('var_name')

Comment: For lack of specificity in your question: Here is a generic answer, If you want the target function to accept datetimes make it do stuff as if a datetime object has been given as a parameter. If you want the target function to accept strings make it do stuff as if a string has been given as a parameter. Types dont change on their own it might be because you are using your parameters as a datetime. (or) i dont understand your question. P.S. Do not post one-line screenshots  (or any) from the console.  Please edit your question with proper resources like code and usage.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have updated the question with all the possible details

Comment: if you use `datetime.strptime(execution_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")` and `execution_date` is `"2021-06-17T08:20:04.631151+00:00"` you should get back a `datatime` object not a string

Comment: Not sure what `Variable.get` returns in that case, but you should be able to convert the returned type to a datetime object without issues - see also my comment #2.

Comment: May I point out that what you are doing seems really weird to begin with? I suggest that before you try to solve this issue you encountered explain WHY you want to do this. I can't think of any reason why would you need to pass execution_date like that between two dags. Simply extract the execution_date when you need it from the DAG itself.

Comment: maybe you have a problem with `execution_date`? -> as the format for the time stamp seem to work fine `datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime("2021-06-17T08:20:04.631151+00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")`

Comment: @Elad I am doing so to check the task_instance details of a task in DAG A from DAG B every 5 minutes

Comment: @braulio Thank you. your suggestion solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow [always stores a string](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e72e5295fd5e710599bc0ecc9a70b0b3b5728f38/airflow/models/variable.py#L172) when using `Variable.set()`. Depending on your needs you can get more precision, but an easy solution will be to transform `execution_date` datetime into isoformat and then convert it back to datetime when getting the value. Code will look like this:

```py
# Import section
from datetime import datetime

# Functions section
def set_execution_date(**kwargs):
    Variable.set('stream_execution_date', kwargs['execution_date'].isoformat())
    status = Variable.get(time_status)

def check_task_status(**kwargs):
    date = datetime.fromisoformat(Variable.get('stream_execution_date'))
    ti = get_task_instance('STREAMING_TEST', 'start_group', date)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried this method however my composer has python version 3 and does not accept fromisoformat so I have used dateutil to resolve my issue.